# jQuery - getJSON Formatting help / syntax

Tags: jquery, getjson

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js">
</script>
<script>

 function readFile() {

$.getJSON("http://www.ellatha.com/apitest.asp", function(data) {

$("#channel").text(data['channel']['display_name']);  
$("#id").text(data['channel']['_id']);

});
  }

$(function () {
    setInterval(function() { readFile() },1000);
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="channel"></div> - <div id="id"></div>
</html>
```

I'm pretty sure I have syntax problems due to how nested this json example is .. if anyone can help point me in the right direction would be grateful! The Json data is on the asp page..I believe its raw json so that shouldnt be a problem.

Json file is basically tells the total number of streams (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dekmx.jpg), then inside the streams block lists all the different data points for each stream (https://i.stack.imgur.com/82Ccz.jpg). I would like to basically make a list of all the channels and their IDs.

Comment: Did you try `$("#channel").text(data['streams']['channel']['display_name']);  `

Comment: Can you provide the *raw* JSON output? It could be that it is returning an array of one dictionary. You may need to do data[0]['channel']['display_name'].

Comment: Looks like it would be: 

data['streams'][0]['channel']['display_name']

Comment: Here is the raw JSON output - http://pastebin.com/2ejLiSxe

Answer (score 0):

You need to first parse the JSON.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data);
$("#channel").text(obj.channel.display_name);  
//OR $("#channel").text(obj.stream.channel.display_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your JSON output you have a **dictionary** of two objects: `_total` and `streams`.

`_total` is a **string** and `streams` is an **list**

A simplified version of your JSON output:

```
{
    "_total": 19,
    "streams: [
                  {
                      "id": 0,
                      "channel": {
                                     "display_name": "Daopa",
                                     "game": "EVE Online"
                                 }
                  },
                  {
                      "id": 1,
                      "channel": {
                                     "display_name": "Name_2",
                                     "game": "League of Legends"
                                 }
                  },
                  {
                      "id": 2,
                      "channel": {
                                     "display_name": "Name_3",
                                     "game": "Dota 2"
                                 }
                  }
             ]
}
```

It is worth knowing that dictionaries are curly brackets { } and lists are square brackets [ ].

[Lists] are referenced by their **index**, starting at 0, while {dictionaries} are referenced by their **key**, e.g. `"display_name"` or `"channel"`.

To get to the display name, you start with the streams dictionary, which contains a list of dictionaries. Those dictionaries contain the `id` and the `channel` dictionary which has `display_name`.

So, to get to the data:

```
data["streams"][0]["id"] // provides id
data["streams"][0]["channel"]["display_name"] // provides display name
```

The `0` is the first object in the list. You can use `data["streams"].length` to find the number of objects in the list to loop through all of them.